# Jquery Datatable Previous & Next Buttons are not align

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

[image]

I have installed Jquery Datatable plugin for my site and it show as the pic above. The Previous and Next Pagination Button are too far from the table. I want to to be align with "Search" or closer to the table.

I cannot find any where to change in "jquery.dataTables.min.js" and "dataTables.bootstrap.css".

Anyone have experience like this?  Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't modify the code of the plugin, the way it works is that you pass options to the plugin to suit your needs. Refer to the plugin's documentation to learn more: https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Comment: Thank you so much. It found the solution from that link.

Comment: Glad to hear it 